# Key needs to be typed two times to display

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using `ubuntu 12.04` and keyboard layout English(US, alternative international).

When I press the key <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd> (single quote & double quote) key, it does not output when pressed first time, it needs to be pressed second time, then only it displays. Same problem with <kbd>~</kbd> key, it also needs to be pressed two times. No any problem with other keys.

How to rectify this strange problem?

Comment: Tried another keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, please try using another keyboard. If the problem goes away, it simply means a defective keyboard.

Comment: defective keyboard ? with all keyboard i have tested (on various machines) this is happening. what if you press space after entering these special characters ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, it's a feature ;) You probably have set a keyboard layout with so called "dead keys". Those keys are mostly not for printing characters themselves, but for *modifying* the following character. For example, if you press "~" followed by "e", you get "ẽ". This is a simple way to type so called "diacritic characters" that are combined of several glyphs like "é", "ñ", "ô", which are used in many languages. To print ~, `, ^ and others themselves, you can combine them with a space character, thus pressing for example "~" followed by the space key. Your solution, pressing the dead key twice, works as well, but is more complicated for the fingers in my opinion.

If you don't want to use the dead key functionality, you can, as you seem to already have, choose a keyboard layout that doesn't feature them.